# import all dimensions and metrics from Google analytic s API through R

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using RGA library to query data from Google analytics using R.

**What I need**:

I need to import all dimensions and metrics from the GA API. Though I understand that all dimensions and metrics are not compatible to be queried together, but there has got to be some way to import all in one query?

Since we are just storing data in the warehouse at the moment, I need to import and store all of it.

Is there a way I can get around this without having to specify every dimension and metric specifically?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract 7 dimensions and 10 metrics per query. There are over 400 dimensions and metrics available. There is no 'database export' option in Google Analytics -- what you seek does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't allow this for several reasons including the protection of their practices, data privacy, and the fact that it would be an absolutely massive drain on them.

A metric like 'Users' simply can't be all downloaded unless you have access to the actual hit data, and the associated client IDs, which Google will never give you.